# Ruby strange behavior with recursive regex

Tags: regex, ruby, pcre, recursive-regex

I recently stumbled into this trying to use a recursive regex:

```rb
'--01-0-01'.scan /0|1|-(\g<0>)(\g<0>)/
#=> [['0', '-0-01']]
```

where it seems that the first recursive pattern matched deeper than expected wile the second one performed normally. This is [confirmed by regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e7dY5h/1) which gives the correct groups (`'-01'` and `'-0-01'`). Is this a strange feature of ruby or is it a buggy implementation?

For the record, this happened while trying to solve [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119754/prefix-notation-to-postfix-notation) code golf question.

Comment: I don't see that code at the linked question, nor do I see any Ruby solutions. Incidentally, your code returns `[["0", "-0-01"]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, I didn't end up posting a solution because I couldn't get regex recursion to work. You're also right about the return value, it's still not what I expect though